# Laravel API - Showing individual file through o2m relationship

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-routing

So I have two models User and File, these are connected with a one-to-many relationship.

I have sorted the API routes and controllers to index all users, show specific user and index all files uploaded by that specific user.  I do not know how to write the logic that will allow this route 127.0.0.1:8001/api/2/files/1 to show the first file uploaded by the 2nd user. So/2(seconduser)/files(shows all)/1(shows only 1 file)

This is my API code:

```
Route::group(["prefix" => "/"], function () {
    Route::get("", [Users::class, "index"]); //show all users

    Route::group(["prefix" => "{user}"], function () {
        Route::get("", [Users::class, "show"]); //show specific user

        Route::group(["prefix" => "/files"], function () {
            Route::get("", [Files::class, "index"]); //show all files

            Route::group(["prefix" => "{file}"], function () {
                Route::get("", [Files::class, "show"]); //trying to show specific file
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Files Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\File;

class Files extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(User $user)
    {
        return $user->files;    
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(User $user, File $file)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Users Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class Users extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return User::all();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a very strange way to declare your routes. What does `artisan route:list -c` show for these routes? Also can you clarify the problem? What are you looking for? `return $file;`?

Comment: | POST | api | App\Http\Controllers\API\Users@store
| GET|HEAD | api| App\Http\Controllers\API\Users@index
| GET|HEAD | api/user| Closure|
| GET|HEAD| api/{user}| App\Http\Controllers\API\Users@show|
| DELETE| api/{user}| App\Http\Controllers\API\Users@destroy|
| PUT | api/{user} | App\Http\Controllers\API\Users@update|
| GET|HEAD | api/{user}/files| App\Http\Controllers\API\Files@index
| POST api/{user}/files| App\Http\Controllers\API\Files@store

Comment: | GET|HEAD | api/{user}/files/{file} | App\Http\Controllers\API\Files@show. 
| DELETE   | api/{user}/files/{file} | App\Http\Controllers\API\Files@destroy. 
| PUT      | api/{user}/files/{file} | App\Http\Controllers\API\Files@update.

Comment: So I am essentially trying to find a way to show single files via the public function show method, however am unsure if its possible this way. I do not know how to write the logic that will allow this route http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/2/files/1 to show the first file uploaded by the 2nd user. So/2(seconduser)/files(shows all)/1(shows only 1 file)

Comment: Please edit your question to include this info, don't put it in comments.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what the problem is. You're specifying a file ID in the URL, that file is put into the `$file` variable. Same as the user.

Comment: I've edited my question to contain that. I am specifying a file ID in the URL, but I don't know how to make it show the actual file? What do I need to enter into the show method to show one file only? The specific ID of the file in the route, but its the logic in the controller I'm unsure of.

Comment: What is wrong with doing the same thing you're doing with `Users::show()`???

Comment: I get this error Argument 1 passed to App\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\Files::show() must be an instance of App\\Models\\File, string given",

Comment: That doesn't agree with the code you've shown here, where `$file` is argument 2.

Comment: Ok that works! However now in postman, if I use this route http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/2/files/2, it shows me the file with an ID of 2, however it was not uploaded by the 2nd user its associated with the 1st? So i'd only like that to show if /api/*1*/files/2 was the route? Thanks for your help man.

Comment: These aren't "first" and "second." They're ID 1 and 2. You're asking for file ID 2, you're getting it. If you want to put additional checks in there, go for it. Just making a files endpoint with the file ID alone would be more reasonable.

Comment: Ok I think I will have a rethink about my routes and stuff as it doesn't seem like my way of going about it makes much sense. Thanks again for your help man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what a typical route declaration would look like. Note the user ID is not relevant to the file request, so the files endpoint is made separate from the users endpoint.

```php
Route::get("/users",              [Users::class, "index"]);
Route::get("/users/{user}",       [Users::class, "show"]);
Route::get("/users/{user}/files", [Files::class, "index"]);
Route::get("/files/{file}",       [Files::class, "show"]);
```

And then in your controller methods, you're simply returning a list or a single item, mostly as in your original code. Note if you're returning API data, you should explicitly [return JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#json-responses).

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\File;

class Files extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function index(User $user)
    {
        return response()->json($user->files);    
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function show(File $file)
    {
        return response()->json($file);
        // or perhaps something like this?
        return response()
            ->download($file->path, $file->name, ["Content-Type" => $file->type]);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class Users extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return response()->json(User::all());
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        return response()->json($user);
    }
}
```